# Getting error 'self._childrens.pop(widget,None) when trying to remove a widget from a TabbedPanel

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to remove a ScreenManager widget from my MainPanel and replace it with a different ScreeManager widget. But I am receiving the error stated above. I've been able to remove other widgets this way (screens) and never got an error but ScreenManagers seem to be different.

main.py

```
class MainPanel(TabbedPanel):
    manager = ObjectProperty()
    usb_manager = ObjectProperty()
    hubtests_sm = ObjectProperty()


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(MainPanel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)



    def switch_sm(self):
        self.manager = self.hubtests_sm
        self.remove_widget(self.usb_manager)
        self.add_widget(self.hubtests_sm)
```

main.kv

```
<MainPanel>:
    id: mp
    manager: usb_manager
    usb_manager: usb_manager


    size_hint: 1,1
    tab_width: 65
    do_default_tab: False
    tab_pos: 'top_right'


    TabbedPanelItem:
        id: usb_tab
        text: 'Usb'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            UsbScreenManager:
                id: usb_manager
```

usb_screen_manager.kv

```
#:import label kivy.uix.label
#:import sla kivy.adapters.simplelistadapter
#:import hvd hub_validation_dict
#:import hvt hub_validation_test2
#:import cfg config

<UsbScreenManager>:
    id: usb_manager 
    h2h: h2h
    hvs: hvs
    v9_icon: v9_icon
    v9_test: v9_test
    c5_icon: c5_icon
    c5_test: c5_test

    H2HScreen:
        id:h2h
    HubValidationScreen:
        id:hvs
    V9ValidationIconScreen
        id: v9_icon
    V9ValidationTestScreen:
        id: v9_test
    C5ValidationIconScreen:
        id: c5_icon
    C5ValidationTestScreen:
        id: c5_test

<H2HScreen>:
    id: h2h
    name: 'h2h'
    BoxLayout:
        id:bl
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TestIcon:
            id: h2hicon
            source: 'h2h.png'


<HubValidationScreen>:
    id: hvs
    name: 'hvs'


    BoxLayout:
        id:bl
        orientation: 'vertical'

        TestIcon:
            id: hubvicon

            source: 'usb_button.png'
            on_press: app.root.switch_sm()<----Attempt to switch screenmanager


  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1465, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "usb_screen_manager.kv", line 53, in <module>
     on_press: app.root.switch_sm()
   File "sam1.py", line 211, in switch_sm
     self.remove_widget(self.usb_manager)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/tabbedpanel.py", line 547, in remove_widget
     self._childrens.pop(widget, None)
 TypeError: pop() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: In the kivy lib this is the function in tabbedpanel.py it states it is erroring out at: http://dpaste.com/1X9QPXY.   When i debugged i found this is being sent into the function: '((<WeakProxy to <__main__.HubTestsScreenManager object at 0x7fa07a623db8>>,), {})' (self, widget) respectively. Does that mean that when it hits that self._childrens.pop(widget, None)  There is nothing in the widget? I cannot see where 2 args are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue because I was misunderstanding the TabbedPanel class. I was calling remove_widget from the MainPanel class when i should have been calling it from the TabbedPanelItem class. So i created an ObjectProperty for that tabbedpanel item in the MainPanel class and used that to remove the screen manager widget.  But because of how they are loaded i ended up having to do a clear_widgets instead then re-add widgets in the correct order.